# how do i pass a variable into search query of Nedb

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, database, nedb

i want to run a search function from the search bar of the website homepage that will query the **nedb ** database with the result gotten from **searchtext ** variable.

How do i pass the searchtext variable into the // as a regular expression? to find a title containing the content of searchtext variable.

Thanks for your help.

```
app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
  const searchtext = req.query.search;


  storydb.find({ title: // }, function (err, output) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(output);
    }
  });

  res.render("search");
});
```

i have checked the documentation for the nedb on npm but don't seem to know how to pass the variable.

```
// Finding all planets whose name contain the substring 'ar' using a regular expression

db.find({ planet: /ar/ }, function (err, docs) { 

 // docs contains Mars and Earth});
```

Comment: Can you try to pass regex in query parameters ? Example: http://localhost:3000/search?regex=/ar/

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman i have tried that using a string "should" http://localhost:3000/search?search=should it works but only when I pass a string. like /should/  but I want to pass a variable into the / /

Comment: const { search } = req.query; and then storydb.find({ title: `/${search}/`, (err, data) => () {}); Have you tried this ?

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman will i then pass search lik so? ...   const { search } = req.query.search; storydb.find({ title: /search/ }, function (err, output) {   I tried it it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: are you using expressjs + which database are using and which npm package using for database connections ? let me check out myself figuring out

Comment: I am using express.js and Nedb database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249609/discussion-between-nsikan-simon-and-bhavya-dhiman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after much research and iteration, I solved the problem. I wrapped the searchtext variable inside the RegExp function and stored that as another variable called regexObj. Then passed that new variable into the storydb.find() function.

```
app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
  const searchtext = req.query.search;
  var regexObj = new RegExp(searchtext);

  storydb.find({ title: regexObj }, function (err, storycontent) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("search", { storycontent });
    }
  });
});
```